# Navigate up/down/left/right through rows and columns matrix with iterators C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, stl, iterator

I am trying to navigate through a `std::set<std::set<char>>` 2x2 matrix.
By moving a 0 left/right/up and down
For exemple I have this matrix :

```
a a O a
a a a a
a a a a
a a a a
```

What I would like to do is be able to change the matrix to have this:

```
a a a O
a a a a
a a a a
a a a a
```

or this:

```
a a a a
a a O a
a a a a
a a a a
```

I'd like to do this using iterators or a better way. It is easy to make the transformation on the same line but I don't know how to make a transformation from one line to an another.

Comment: are you sure it's supposed to be *set* rather than *vector*?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it will be better to use a Vector

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to store the coordinates of your `0` (**optionally** along with the actual container, which in many situations would be redundant though).

So on moving the 0 to the right, you'd simply ++x (and if you're also storing the actual container of chars, you know where the old zero is, so you change it to the background symbol and put a 0 in the new coordinates).

```
MoveRight()
{
    container[x][y] = 'a'; //optional
    ++x;
    container[x][y] = '0'; //optional
}
```

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. But 'char' was an exemple. What if I have std::vector<std::vector<MyObject*>> and I want to move for exemple MyObject pointer somewhere else in the Matrix, put this object one line down for exemple. I hope you understand. Thank you again

Comment: @NicolasGng: I don't see how your example with MyObject* should be any different than the idea in my answer?